# How to get the value of tabulator-field attribute of an html generated by cell.getElement()

Tags: tabulator

Tabulator's cell.getElement() function returns a div containing the **tabulator-field** attribute.

How can I get the value of that attribute?

The following html has been returned by cell.getElement()

```
<div class="tabulator-cell tabulator-editable" role="gridcell" tabulator-field="price" tabindex="0"
style="width: 217px; text-align: center; height: 30px;">&nbsp;</div>
```

Thanks in advance